# Snowflake: can an SQS-SNS provide granular path for COPY INTO?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am loading data from an S3 folder to Snowflake, which also has a lot of sub-folders. Due to design constraints, I cannot change the folder structure nor deleting the loaded files. When reading some [best practices](https://www.analytics.today/blog/top-3-snowflake-performance-tuning-tactics) of ELT, they suggest loading the data into a granular path like this:

```
-- Simple method:  Scan the entire stage
copy into sales_table
  from @landing_data
  pattern='.*[.]csv';

-- Most Flexible method:  Limit within directory
copy into sales_table
  from @landing_data/sales/transactions/2020/05
  pattern='.*[.]csv';

-- Fastest method:  A named file
copy into sales_table
  from @landing_data/sales/transactions/2020/05/sales_050.csv;
```

However, like mentioned above, my best one is only `@landing_data/sales/transactions`, which will grow based on the date and make the performance decrease over time.  When reading the [guide to use SNS topic](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#step-3-create-a-pipe-with-auto-ingest-enabled), it says that:

> Note that the pipe will only copy files to the ingest queue triggered by event notifications via the SNS topic.

I have some questions:

- If I understand correctly, it means that SNS will provide the path of that file for Snowpipe, which makes the loading process already use a granular path?
- If the above is wrong, is there any way I can make sure that the performance does not decrease over time? I am not allowed to change the S3 structure nor deleting the file after loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I understand correctly, it means that SNS will provide the path of that file for Snowpipe, which makes the loading process already use a granular path?

Correct. From https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-s3.html#step-3-create-a-pipe-with-auto-ingest-enabled:

> ```
> Data files are loaded in a stage.
>
> An S3 event notification informs Snowpipe via an SQS queue that files are ready to load. Snowpipe copies the files into a queue.
>
> A Snowflake-provided virtual warehouse loads data from the queued files into the target table based on parameters defined in the
> ```
>
> specified pipe.

It's "loads data from the queued files" that indicates what you're looking for here. This saves Snowpipe from having to list the contents of the folder (which is the primary contributor to performance issues on paths that aren't granular).

Note that you don't *need* Snowpipe for this - `COPY INTO` has the `FILES` option which lets you specify individual files, too.

Comment: Can you clarify "@landing_data/sales/transactions, which will grow based on the date". Do you mean that you cannot have a date and any sub folders in transactions? Just a large list of files like @landing_data/sales/transactions/yyyymmddttss.csv?

Adding on to @Hotchips, if your file pattern is deterministic you can schedule and load your files using bulk loading and you don't NEED Snowpipe and SQS if there are other constraints or a desire to limit complexity.

Comment: @TimBenroeck regarding this, currently the data pipeline creates a folder for each year, then month, date and hour, minute, etc. So it will be `@landing_data/sales/transactions/YYYY/MM/DD/HH/MM` which is continuously created based on the current timestamp of the extraction.

Comment: In that case, you shouldn't hit the performance issue being called out in the best practices because you would really be doing the middle "most flexible" method if you used the pattern option.   This will limit the amount of files being compared with the metadata. 

Something like:
`set mypattern = '\.*'||to_char(current_timestamp(), 'transactions/YYYY/MM/DD/HH24/MI')||'\.*';
list @MYDB.public.stage pattern=$mypattern;`

There are a lot of considerations and the Snowpipe route is very flexible and performant but I did want to make sure I fully understood the ask.